# Ubuntu 16.04 - Atheros AR5007ug does not work

Tags: wireless, atheros

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 lately. On Windows 7, my USB Wi-Fi has worked properly while on Ubuntu I cannot find any network at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0280]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'; rfkill list`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, if your WLAN chip is working properly, you should have installed the third-party drivers in the installation so it's supported. If you are sure that your WLAN chip doesn't have a problem, go to Terminal (press the Launcher icon and search up Terminal in the search bar and double-clicking) and type `sudo su` and type your password. Second, type `ip a` (if you can't get output result, type `apt install nettools -y`) and you should get the list of wireless cards inactive and active. To activate your primary wireless card (wlp3s0, wlan0, etc), type `ifconfig (wireless card) up`. Then, type `ifconfig` and you should see your wireless card up. Hope this helps.